# Is there any way of making a buttons callback have exactly the same function as a keystroke in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a few buttons on my program that input text into an entry widget, but I need that input to run through a validatecommand to have it run properly, such as with input from a keystroke, is there any way this is possible?

Comment: [ttk::entry](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm#M39) has some validation features that will do what you want.  I don't know how to translate those to python though.

Answer (score 1):

Give your function an optional argument. You can then call it with or without a keystroke.

```
def callback(self, event=None):
    pass
```

Note that `self` above assumes an object-oriented Tkinter application, which is generally less hassle than other approaches.